# get DATETIME from this output

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I am using some scheduler framework which outputs the following:

> Wed Feb 12 2014 08:40:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)

I want to process this data in order for me to save it into a database table which is currently set as DATETIME. Any idea how I can process this data using PHP Date/Datetime functions? I need to find a more appropriate solution, aside from string manipulations.

Output should be in the following format:

> Y-m-d h:i:s

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you can't use [`strtotime()`](http://us2.php.net/strtotime) or [`createFromFormat`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: yeah, sorry.. strtotime() is what I needed. had just got it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple answer to a simple question... :|

Solution #1:

> date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($TIME));

This solution returns a different date and time for some reasons.

Solution #2:

> $TIME = 'Wed Feb 12 2014 08:40:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)';
>
> $dateStarted = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s e+', $TIME);
>
> $start = $dateStarted->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Output will be something like this:

> 2014-02-12 08:40:00

Comment: TIME is the variable name for the DATE string.
$start = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($time));